# Info with mod_rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, optimization, mod-rewrite

I have been trying forever to get rid of the .php from my site. I want it to look like example.com/about instead of example.com/about.php. I have it to were it will rewrite it so i can type it in as example.com/about but i want it to were when i click on a link on my website to go to example.com/about it loads the url as example.com/about and not example.com/about.php. Overall i would like it so that whenever someone loads anything on my page the end of the url doesnt have the .php. My .htaccess right now looks like so,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

You wouldn't have to change your site's structure as it simply targets "malformed" URIs in the form of "http://x.com/page" without an extension at the end. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

> but i want it to were when i click on a link on my website to go to example.com/about it loads the url as example.com/about and not example.com/about.php

To fix that, you need to change links from your site from `example.com/about.php` to `example.com/about`. You can still do a redirect when links "in the wild" still point to the `.php` URLs, but unless you change the links on your site to remove the extension, your're causing every page load to hit your server twice.

As for the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\.php[\?\ ]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]
```

I'm not sure how your rules to put the php extension back is even working, since you're matching for a trailing slash but when you check the file with `-f`, you'll have a stray trailing slash in your filename: e.g. `/some/path/to/the_file/.php` instead of `/some/path/to/the_file.php`

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+?)/?
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```